# Is there a "Excel Control" for Winform application(C#)?

Tags: .net, excel

what we want to do is to display the result of some calculation in a excel looking control embedded inside our own WinForm Application.
why datagrid is not helpful is that we also need the chart function from excel.

so, is there such a control that can be directly drag-drop onto the GUI? and how to use it?

thank you in advance!

Comment: You can always embed Excel itself. But do you really need the charts to be on the same worksheet as the numbers?

Answer (score 1):

Try the [Office Web Components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Web_Components).